# Дано одномерный массив. Заменить все отрицательные элементы их модулями

Tags: c++

```cpp
const int  n = 10;
int i, max = -1, A[n];
for (i = -1; i < n; i++)
  std::cin >> A[i];
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
  if (A[i] > A[max])
    max = i;
for (i = -1; i < max; i++)
  if (A[i] < 0)
    A[i] = 0;
for (i = -1; i < n; i++)
  std::cout << A[i] << "";
```

Я сделал так, что если число отрицательное, то оно будет отображаться 0. Вот только не могу понять, как сделать чтобы элементы были модулями. Например, число -1 будет 1 или число 2 будет -2.

Comment: "элементы были модулями. Например, число -1 будет 1 или число 2 будет -2." - а почему -2 вы считаете модулем числа 2?

Answer (score 1):

Если он **уже дан**, то, например,

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) A[i] = abs(A[i]);
```

Если же его еще надо вводить -

```
const int  n = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> A[i];
    A[i] = abs(A[i]);
};

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << A[i] << "";
```

Можно исправить ваше -

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (A[i] < 0)
        A[i] = -A[i];
```

Но почему вы начинаете индексацию с `-1` - для меня неразрешимая загадка...

Answer (score 0):

```
const int n = 10;
int i, max = 0, A[n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    std::cin >> A[i];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (A[i] > A[max])
        max = i;

for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
    if (A[i] < 0)
        A[i] = 0;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    std::cout << A[i] << "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{    
    constexpr size_t size = 5; // константа этапа компиляции
    int arr[size];
    istream_iterator<remove_reference<decltype(arr[0])>::type> it(cin); // начальный итератор ввода
    istream_iterator<remove_reference<decltype(arr[0])>::type> endit; // конечный итератор ввода

    copy(it, endit, arr); // скопировать из входного потока данных в массив
    for_each(begin(arr), end(arr), [](auto& i) { i = abs(i); }); // преобразовать в положительные числа
    for_each(begin(arr), end(arr), [](const auto& i) { cout << i << endl; }); // вывести на экран

    return 0;
}
```

Заметьте, чтобы остановить ввод данных, нужно нажать `CTRL+D`